# Do the pupils of an eye emit blackbody radiation?

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation

A [blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#:%7E:text=A%20black%20body%20or%20blackbody,frequency%20or%20angle%20of%20incidence.&text=It%20is%20an%20ideal%20emitter,body%20at%20the%20same%20temperature.), by definition is an ideal system that absorbs all radiation incident on it.

If a good approximation of a black body is a small hole leading to the inside of a hollow object, then am I right in saying that the pupils of an eye are a good approximation of a black body because they are also holes to a (near) spherical cavity?

If yes, do they also emit blackbody radiation in accordance with the [Planck wavelength distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), and is this why they appear black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any approximation has a region of applicability - that is the conditions where one can apply it or not:

- Human eye obviously absorbs the radiation only in a certain range - e.g., it si totally transparent for gamma rays, which are also a part of the Planck spectrum (sinc ethe latter includes all frequencies up to infinity).
- Human eye reflects some of the radiation (due to the different refractive index of the lens, immediately behind the pupil (see [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupil#/media/File:Schematic_diagram_of_the_human_eye_en.svg)).
- Not all of the absorbed radiation is re-emitted (which is one of the conditions for the black body as related to the Planck's law).

**Remark:** Note also that one can define the black body radiation without resorting to a (largely historical) concept of *the black body* - as an equilibrium state of a photon gas: see, e.g., the discussion in [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644253/247642).